# Project Euler #2 in Python, not running anything

Tags: python

```
def fibo(n):
  if n == 0 or n == 1:
    return n
  else:
    return fibo(n - 1) + fibo(n - 2)


def main():
  total = 0
  a = 0
  while a < 4000000:
    if a % 2 == 0:
      total += a
      fibo(total)
  print(total)
```

**My code isn't running anything. I am just playing around with Python (so nothing serious but just need help)**

Comment: Change `||` to `or`

Comment: Does Python not allow || or is that just a Python 3 thing?

Comment: Your code does run anything because you merely define two routines and exit without calling either.

Comment: Language syntax is easy to look up -- how did that not answer your question?

Comment: Python syntax is `or`, `and` and `not` instead of `||` , `&&` and `!`

Comment: What if I get rid the main() and just have the while loop outside of a function?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: You're trying to do something that requires calculating 2 million Fibonacci numbers, and you're using an exponential-time algorithm to calculate each one. Just calculating the 4 millionth one is going to take a ridiculously long time. Fortunately, when you get to a recursion depth of around 1000, it'll raise a runtime error at you instead of making you wait until you're a decomposing skeleton, but it'll still take quite a while to get that far.

Comment: It is bad form to substantially modify the question after you've asked it. By modifying your question (from "*My code is giving me a syntax error*" to "*My code isn't running anything.*"), you've invalidated the above comments and any answer that someone was working on. If your question is answered, move on. If you have a new question, ask it in a new post.

Comment: @kcook: A better design is to leave the `main` there, and just add a `main()` call at the top level. You may want to guard it with `if __name__ == '__main__': main()` if you want to be able to import the module to reuse its functions, as well as being able to run it as a script.

Comment: Sorry for not saying that I figured out it was or rather than || I should of clarified that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def fibo(n):
  if n == 0 or n == 1:
    return n
  else:
    return fibo(n - 1) + fibo(n - 2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  total = 0
  a = 0
  while a < 4000000:
    if a % 2 == 0:
      total += a
      fibo(total)
  print(total)
```

Try using this.
Or simply

```
def fibo(n):
      if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return n
      else:
        return fibo(n - 1) + fibo(n - 2)

total = 0
a = 0
while a < 4000000:        
if a % 2 == 0:          
total += a
fibo(total)      
print(total)
```